# Jetpack compose and AuthStatelistener firebase

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

Hi i am trying to create an app in jetpack compose with MVVM architechture and with firebase.
I am now wondering where you would go about placing the AuthStatelistener in this case. I cant find anything about it on the web. The thing is that implementing that statelistnener does not work quz you do not use classes in Jetpack compose you use functions. and you cant call screens in the MainActivity. So how would you then check if the user is still signed in??? There is nothing about it on the web. There is a bunch of tutorials on the web about MVVM structure and ordinary xml layouts but nothing what i can find about jetpack compose?????

Comment: What you are looking for is explained in this article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8), including everything is related to the [auth listener](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAnonymousAuthentication/blob/c3949a041d7672b9af8148a2f55d9c6be5c68af6/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseanonymousauthentication/data/repository/AuthRepositoryImpl.kt#L46).

Comment: Thanks this really helped though i do have some trouble with the Authrepository interface i made a fun returning a flow but that gives me an error in the implementation that says that the callbackflow is not the correct return type?

Comment: @jens: If you're having trouble implementing the guidance/use-case, show us the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.